# Java 2d detect collision

Tags: java, 2d, collision

Dynamic objects (tanks) intersects with the
 borders of  the map. I should disable movement depending on rectangles involved into collision.
How I can detect the end of collision?

[image]

P.S. sorry for my English.

Comment: I use rectangle.intersects() and it worked. Problem in notify my objects when collision is ended.

Answer (score 0):

You can check for intersections-

```
public static boolean overlapRectangles (final Rectangle r1, final Rectangle r2) {
    if (
            r1.x < r2.x + r2.width 
         && r1.x + r1.width > r2.x 
         && r1.y < r2.y + r2.height 
         && r1.y + r1.height > r2.y
    )
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

You may want to read [this article](http://www.wildbunny.co.uk/blog/2011/04/20/collision-detection-for-dummies/).

Answer (score 0):

In Java 7 you can use public boolean intersects(Rectangle r).

```
if ( r1.intersects(r2) ) {
    //do something...
}
```

What do you mean more exactly about detecting the end of collision?

Comment: Notify tank when objects not intersects.

Comment: How is the movement of your tank defined? Is it listening for input from the user or predefined? In that loop in which you refresh it's position, check every time when there is a new position whether the tank rectangle intersects any of the border rectangles.